# Original formula of Einstein time dilation

Tags: special-relativity

The formula of time dilation at constant speed v is known. 
The formula $T_0'= T /\gamma$ where gamma is the Lorentz factor.

I would be interested, as Einstein's original formula was.

I've checked in "Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Körper". 
Something was on page 904 (original page number of Einstein).

There is indicated $\tau=t*\sqrt{1-v^2/V^2} = t-(1-\sqrt{(v^2/V^2)})*t$

$V$ is the speed of light.

Is that the original formula?

Answer (score 1):

The [Lorentz factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor) is
$$\gamma=\frac1{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$$
so for time dilation we have
$$\Delta t'=\gamma\Delta t$$
where $t'$ is taken in the frame where the clock is moving at speed $v$ relative to the frame in which $t$ is measured.

So the formula from Einstein, in the notation I mentioned above, would be
$$\Delta t=\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}\Delta t'$$
where we use the $\Delta$'s to emphasize that it is elapsed or relative time.

For the last equality, you should be aware that you made a small typo. It should read:
$$=\Delta t'-(1-\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2})\Delta t'$$
where a factor of $\Delta t'$ was simply added and subtracted.